# Using installed version number as a variable

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to retrieve the version number of various installed applications and then perform an action if they are lower than a certain value. For example:

```
Dim regKey As RegistryKey
        Dim ver As ???????
        regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Adobe Flash Player ActiveX")
        ver = regKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
                MessageBox.Show(ver)
            If ver < 11.4.402.287 Then
            'Install updated version of software in question
        End If
        regKey.Close()
```

How could I define Ver to be able to easily do a greater/less than check?  I've tried:

```
Dim ver as integer
Dim ver as decimal
```

Both of these return "Additional information: Conversion from string "11.4.402.287" to type 'Decimal' is not valid."

Comment: You'll probably need to parse the string into the major/minor/build portions and make your determination based on that (most likely only the first two number - major and minor versions - will be of interest.  In the example above, 11 would be the major version number and 4 the minor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Parse and check assuming you are looking at first two components:

```
Dim va = Ver.split("."c)
If va(0) < 11 OrElse (va(0) = 11) and va(1) < 4) Then 
    'Install updated ....
End If
```

Comment: This definitely looks like the simplest approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

A regex for this might look something like:

```
(?<major>\d+)(\.(?<minor>\d+)(\.(?<revision>\d+)(\.(?<build>\d+))?)?)?
```

You could then extract the version numbers using groups:

```
Dim l_version As Regex = New Regex("(?<major>\d+)(\.(?<minor>\d+)(\.(?<revision>\d+)(\.(?<build>\d+))?)?)?")
Dim l_versionMatch As Match = l_version.Match( "1.2.3" )

Dim l_major As String = l_versionMatch.Groups("major").Value
```